# Headmaster - Vice Headmaster?

Tags: phrase-request

Can I say Headmaster and Vice-Headmaster for the persons involved in a school management?

I have read this https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159779/managing-director-in-a-school-below-university-level but I still need to make sure how to use the *Vice-Headmaster*

Comment: I don't think this is a language question, since literally "vice-" could be used with any second in command. Whether it is an actual title somewhere has to do with title nomenclature in an organization.

Comment: @user3169 for me, it is a language question! Or, can you suggest another word/phrase for a person who assists the headmaster?

Comment: Then [*vice-*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vice_2): "*prefix* - **Vice-** is used before a rank or title to indicate that someone is next in importance to the person who holds the rank or title mentioned."

Comment: `Assistant Headmaster` is used commonly, as is `assistant principal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position below that of the *[headmaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_teacher)* in a school is the *[deputy headmaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deputy_head_teacher)*. For example,

> There were smiles, tears and hugs at the gates of Trinity Grammar as
>   deputy headmaster Rohan Brown made an emotional return to his beloved
>   school.

(taken from https://www.theage.com.au/national/victoria/no-long-hair-trinity-grammar-deputy-headmaster-returns-to-school-20180417-p4za0e.html)

> My name is Jason Parker and I am very proud to be your Deputy
>   Headmaster.

(taken from https://www.meadowridge.bc.ca/about/school-leadership/deputy-headmaster)

Comment: It was in my school but could you give more details in your answer a citation from a dictionary for example one word answers do not provided much information,